# Using methods inside functions to be used in layout files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, .net-7.0

I've created a file called `Functions.cshtml` and have added the following block:

```
@functions {
    public static string GetTitle(string title) => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(title) ? $"{title} - " : string.Empty;
}
```

In my `Layout.cshtml` how do I use this function? I've tried `@Functions.GetTitle("Test")` but it doesn't seem to find the function at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining your functions directly in a Razor view, it's better to create a helper class in your project, and place your functions in this class. For example, it's better to create a helper class in your project (in a folder called Static, for example), and place your functions in this class. Example:

**1. Create static helpers :**

```
namespace YourNameSpace.Static;

    public static class Helpers
    {
        public static string GetTitle(string title) => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(title) ? $"{title} - " : string.Empty;
    
        // Add more helpers methods here
    }
```

**1. Use Helpers in views : in any razor view**

```
@using YourNameSpace.Static;
<title>@Helpers.GetTitle("Page Title")</title>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.